# Why apachebench is constantly repeating its requests in HTTP 1.0 session through the same connection?

Tags: python, http, sockets, apachebench

I have made a simple python script with kind of HTTP server:

```
import SocketServer

response  = b'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nDate: Mon, 1 Jan 1996 01:01:01 GMT\r\n'
response += b'Content-Type: text/plain\r\nContent-Length: 14\r\n\r\n'
response += b'Hello, world!\n'

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        while True:
            line = self.rfile.readline().strip()
            print "{} {}:{} wrote: {}".format(self.connection, self.client_address[0], self.client_address[1], line)
            if not line:
                self.wfile.write(response)        
                print 'Sent hello world'
                #break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Now I launch ab to do 1 request through 1 conenction:
    ab -n1 -c1 http://127.0.0.1:9999/

When I don't close the connection after response, expecting the client to close the socket on its end once it receives my response, something strange happens.

Ab repeats all the time sending the same request through the same conenction:

```
~$ python2.7 ./socket_server.py
<socket._socketobject object at 0x1068ca600> 127.0.0.1:64626 wrote: GET / HTTP/1.0
<socket._socketobject object at 0x1068ca600> 127.0.0.1:64626 wrote: Host: 127.0.0.1:9999
<socket._socketobject object at 0x1068ca600> 127.0.0.1:64626 wrote: User-Agent: ApacheBench/2.3
<socket._socketobject object at 0x1068ca600> 127.0.0.1:64626 wrote: Accept: */*
<socket._socketobject object at 0x1068ca600> 127.0.0.1:64626 wrote:
Sent hello world
<socket._socketobject object at 0x1068ca600> 127.0.0.1:64626 wrote: GET / HTTP/1.0
<socket._socketobject object at 0x1068ca600> 127.0.0.1:64626 wrote: Host: 127.0.0.1:9999
<socket._socketobject object at 0x1068ca600> 127.0.0.1:64626 wrote: User-Agent: ApacheBench/2.3
<socket._socketobject object at 0x1068ca600> 127.0.0.1:64626 wrote: Accept: */*
<socket._socketobject object at 0x1068ca600> 127.0.0.1:64626 wrote:
Sent hello world
<socket._socketobject object at 0x1068ca600> 127.0.0.1:64626 wrote: GET / HTTP/1.0
<socket._socketobject object at 0x1068ca600> 127.0.0.1:64626 wrote: Host: 127.0.0.1:9999
<socket._socketobject object at 0x1068ca600> 127.0.0.1:64626 wrote: User-Agent: ApacheBench/2.3
<socket._socketobject object at 0x1068ca600> 127.0.0.1:64626 wrote: Accept: */*
<socket._socketobject object at 0x1068ca600> 127.0.0.1:64626 wrote:
Sent hello world
```

... and it repeats infinetly through the same socket.

I have tried to read raw data from socket:

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler2(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        while True:
            self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
            print self.data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler2)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Ab still doesn't even try to wait the response, it rushes with tonns of requests in the same connection.

Why? Is it some kind of connection re-using in HTTP 1.0 I'm missing? Should I always close the connection regardless of data coming next after first \r\n\r\n pair?

What would be the proper httperf parameters to try to reproduce the same behaviour?

Comment: For what it is worth I see the same behavior from ApacheBench/2.3, it is not what I expected.